# Get value from JSON in PHP

Tags: php

I'd like to get specific value from JSON.

URL: https://api.darksky.net/forecast/92cf27941c6ea888652ba37de4da4044/37.8267,-122.4233

I am trying like below

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/92cf27941c6ea888652ba37de4da4044/37.8267,-122.4233', true);

    echo $data['currently']['temperature'];
?>
```

But it is not working. Can anyone help me on it? I'd like to get currently > temperature value only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do following changes `json_decode('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/92cf27941c6ea888652ba37de4da4044/37.8267,-122.4233', true);` will try to decode  url string it will not decode result. For that you have to execute this url.

```
$url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/92cf27941c6ea888652ba37de4da4044/37.8267,-122.4233";
$json_data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json_data, TRUE);
echo $data['currently']['temperature'];
```

Comment: Glad to help @RaselAhmed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't call json url directly. You need a file function for this. Here is a sample.

```
$json_url = "http://awebsites.com/file.json";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
  <?php
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/92cf27941c6ea888652ba37de4da4044/37.8267,-122.4233', true));

        echo $data->currently->temperature;
    ?>
```

Comment: Easy & simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't read file directly without using **curl** or **file_get_contents**

Snippet below to get data

```
<?php

$your_url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/92cf27941c6ea888652ba37de4da4044/37.8267,-122.4233";
$get_data = file_get_contents($your_url);
$data = json_decode($get_data, TRUE);
 echo $data['currently']['temperature'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get contents of page first using curl or file_get_contents. Try Following Code

```
    $url = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/92cf27941c6ea888652ba37de4da4044/37.8267,-122.4233';

    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($result, true);

    echo $data['currently']['temperature'];
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the file_get_contents.